# Flume 1.5.0 + Reading log data from remote Linux server

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I am new to `Flume`. I have `Flume` and `Hadoop` installed in one server and logs are available in other server.

Through `Flume`, I am trying to read the logs. Here is my configuration file.

```
# Define a memory channel called ch1 on agent1
agent1.channels.ch1.type = memory

# Define an Avro source called avro-source1 on agent1 and tell it
# to bind to 0.0.0.0:41414. Connect it to channel ch1.
agent1.sources.avro-source1.type = syslogtcp
agent1.sources.avro-source1.bind = 10.209.4.224
agent1.sources.avro-source1.port = 5140

# Define a logger sink that simply logs all events it receives
# and connect it to the other end of the same channel.
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://delvmplldsst02:54310/flume/events
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.batchSize = 20
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0

# Finally, now that we've defined all of our components, tell
# agent1 which ones we want to activate.
agent1.channels = ch1
agent1.sources = avro-source1
agent1.sinks = hdfs-sink1

#chain the different components together
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.channel = ch1
agent1.sources.avro-source1.channels = ch1
```

I am not sure what exact source type to use in this scenario. I am starting `Flume agent` like below in the other server:

```
 bin/flume-ng agent --conf-file conf/flume.conf -f /var/log/wtmp -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n agent1
```

Here is the log for the above command

```
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Configuration provider starting
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:conf/flume.conf
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: hdfs-sink1 Agent: agent1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:hdfs-sink1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [agent1]
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Creating channels
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO channel.DefaultChannelFactory: Creating instance of channel ch1 type memory
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Created channel ch1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source avro-source1, type syslogtcp
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO sink.DefaultSinkFactory: Creating instance of sink: hdfs-sink1, type: hdfs
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Hadoop Security enabled: false
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Channel ch1 connected to [avro-source1, hdfs-sink1]
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO node.Application: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{avro-source1=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.SyslogTcpSource{name:avro-source1,state:IDLE} }} sinkRunners:{hdfs-sink1=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@5954864a counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{ch1=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: ch1}} }
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO node.Application: Starting Channel ch1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: ch1: Successfully registered new MBean.
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: ch1 started
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO node.Application: Starting Sink hdfs-sink1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO node.Application: Starting Source avro-source1
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: hdfs-sink1: Successfully registered new MBean.
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: hdfs-sink1 started
14/06/25 00:37:17 INFO source.SyslogTcpSource: Syslog TCP Source starting...
```

Here the the ptocess is getting stuck and not at all proceeding further. I am not knowing where it would have went wrong

Could someone please help me on the same

I did not installed flume in the server where I have log files. Shall I install flume there as well??

Flume version using - 1.5.0
Hadoop version installed - 1.0.4

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure the other server to forward its syslog output to your logging server. That configuration depends on exactly which syslog daemon you are running.

The log output makes it appear that it started correctly to me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably from syslog.
Your flume appears to have started fine , the reason it appears to be idle is that it is not recieving any events from syslog.

make sure your syslog daemon is sending events to 
port = 5140
and for 
agent1.sources.avro-source1.bind , you can bind to any source by replacing ip with 0.0.0.0 (if you plan to listen from multiple servers)

you can check that in  `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

*.* @hostnameofflume:flumesourceport
in your case it should be

`*.* @10.209.4.224:5140`  (assuming this ip is of your flume host)